# Radiobuttons and Checkbuttons not appearing in window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm writing a program that draws a rectangle or oval in a top frame depending on whether or not the user selects it via a radiobutton. There is a check button that determines whether the oval is filled as well. Both buttons are on the bottom frame. But for some reason when I run the code, it displays the window, but not the buttons themselves. How do I fix this?

Here's my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class GeometricFigures:
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title("Radiobuttons and Checkbuttons")
        self.canvas = Canvas(self.window, width = 300, height = 100, bg = "white")
        self.canvas.pack()

    def drawButtons(self):
        self.bottomframe = Frame(self.window)
        self.bottomframe.pack()

        self.check = IntVar()
        cbtFilled = Checkbutton(self.bottomframe, variable = self.check, value = 0,
                                text = "Filled", command =     self.processCheckbutton).pack(side = LEFT)
        self.radio = IntVar()
        rbRectangle = Radiobutton(self.bottomframe, variable = self.radio, value = 1,
                                  text = "Rectangle", command = self.processRadiobutton.pack())

        rbOval = Radiobutton(self.bottomframe, text = "Oval", variable = self.radio,
                             value = 2, command = self.processRadiobutton.pack())

        cbtFilled.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        rbRectangle.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        rbOval.grid(row = 1, column = 4)

    def processCheckbutton(self):
        print("The check button is " +
              ("checked " if self.check.get() == 1 else "unchecked"))
    def processRadiobutton(self):
        print(("Rectangle" if self.radio.get() == 1 else "Oval")
              + " is selected ")

    def drawRect(self):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(30, 10, 270, 60, tags = "rect")

    def drawFillOval(self):
        self.canvas.create_oval(30, 10, 270, 60, fill = 'blue', tags = "oval")

    def drawOval(self):
        self.canvas.create_oval(30, 10, 270, 60, tags = "oval")

    def main(self):
        test = GeometricFigures()
        if self.check.get() == 1:
            test.drawFillOval()
        if self.radio.get() == 1:
            test.drawRect()
        else:
            test.drawOval()
        test.drawButtons()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mix pack() and grid() which has unknown results.  Choose one or the other and stick with it throughout the program.  Also, if you print cbtFilled you will see that it is None because pack() is the last function called and it returns None.  Put pack() on a separate line so cbtFilled contains a Tkinter ID for the Checkbutton.  And obviously your indentation is off.

Comment: I fixed what you suggested, but I get the same thing. Can you edit in the fix so I can see what you mean? Thanks a lot

Comment: @user3105664: mixing pack and grid like in the above code does _not_ have unknown results, and is perfectly acceptable. You can't mix them in the same parent widget, but in an app as a whole it's not only possible, but a recommended way to do things.

Comment: Your code can't possibly display a window with no checkbuttons, it has several errors. There is no `main` function (only a main method in a class you never instantiate), you reference the intvars before you create them, you use illegal options in the checkbutton code, and you are calling pack on a function rather than a widget. And finally, you never call the `mainloop` method of the root window.

Comment: I was referring to cbtFilled, and the OP's pack and grid for the same variable (it equals None for the grid but that has nothing to do with the principle).  And of course the same for the two others, rbRectangle and rbOval.